# Why is iteration not working correctly in Python within a method?

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, methods

I know that this is a simple question, but unfortunately it is not working as expected. I am referring to a Tutorial on https://towardsdatascience.com/playing-with-time-series-data-in-python-959e2485bff8 and have stuck at the situation that on calling the below method, the length of the arrays returned always appears to be 1.

```
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
  dataX, dataY = [], []
  for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back):
    print('i:',i) #Using this for debugging
    a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), 0]
    dataX.append(a)
    dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])  
    print(len(dataY))
    return np.array(dataX),np.array(dataY)
```

Here is where I call the method:

```
look_back = 2
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test,look_back)
```

The length of train and test is

```
print(len(train),len(test))
584, 147
```

Received Output:

```
i: 0
1
i: 0
1
```

While the expected output is:

```
582
145
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You `return` statement is inside the loop, so it's executed in the first run and exit the function. Move it outside the loop.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks a lot.